# Limit of $\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-1}$ as $x \to 1$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-1}$$ Hello, I am trying to solve this problem. May you give me a hint how to solve problems like this without l'hospital?

Thank you very much. (I tried factorising etc. but I always end up with $0$ divided by $0$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{x^{2}-x}{x^2-1} = \frac{x(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{x}{x+1}$

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. I was blind. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @Paul no problem!

Comment: May I ask how did you factorise $$x^2-1$$ though?

Comment: Just $x^{2}-a^{2}=(x-a)(x+a)$

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to factor out the $x$ on the top and expand the difference of squares on the bottom (follow this [link](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/polynomial-factorization/factoring-quadratics-diff-of-squares/a/factoring-quadratics-difference-of-squares) if you don't know what a difference of squares is). Then, there will be something that you can cancel out which will help you simplify the expression. After that, you can use the direct substitution method to finally find the limit. Here are the steps:

\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-1}
&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-1^2}\\ 
&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x\cancel{(x-1)}}{\cancel{(x-1)}(x+1)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x}{x+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful.